# The LCD of my MSP430 development board doesn't work when voltage biases are generated externally

Tags: lcd, msp430

I am programming the LCD of my [MSP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN) development board ([MSP-EXP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP-EXP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN)), and I have a question regarding generating VLCD (V1) and LCD biasing.

The development board got a 14-segment, 6 digit LCD connected to the MSP430 ([MSP-EXP40FR6989 User Guide pg 11/41](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau627a/slau627a.pdf?ts=1597115662607&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FMSP-EXP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP-EXP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)), and the MSP430 got an LCD module (LCD_B and LCD_C module).

In order to turn on a segment, we set the relevant segment line (Sx) and the COM line (COMx), by writing a certain word to the LCDCMEMx registers.

These are the things we need to configure before writing values into the LCDCMEMx registers:

- Set th Vlcd (V1) to be sourced from internally from the charge pump or externally.
- set the value of Vlcd (V1)
- set the bias, 1/2 bias or 1/3 bias.
- configure the source of V2 - V4, internally or externally (R23 pin, R13/LCDREF pin, R03 pin)
- Source V5 from Vss or from external R03 pin
- set the LCD's frequency (flcd)
- Add a capacitor to the LCDCAP/R33 pin.
- set the correct segments and COMs using the LCDCMEMx registers
- Turn on the LCD

I would like to have V1 sourced internally, 1/3 bias, V2 - V4 sourced externally from R23 and R13/LCDREF pins, V5 sourced from R03 pin, flcd = 512Hz, Vlcd (V1) = 3.44V, the MSP-EXP430FR6989 has a capacitor and resistor network attached to it ([MSP-EXP430FR6989 User Guide pg 29/41](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau627a/slau627a.pdf?ts=1597115662607&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FMSP-EXP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP-EXP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)).

As you can see in the code below this is the value written to LCDCVCTL (SFR responsible for the LCD_C module's voltage) `LCDCVCTL = 0x1E68` which is `0001 1110 0110 1000`

That is the code relevant to the LCD Voltage and bias generation FYI

```
#include <msp430.h> 

//code

#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

#define TURN_ON_LCD     (LCDCCTL0 |= LCDON)
#define TURN_OFF_LCD    (LCDCCTL0 &= (~LCDON))
#define CLEAR_LCD_MEM   (LCDCMEMCTL |= LCDCLRM)

//code

void init_LCD (void);
void show_Char (unsigned char ch, unsigned int pos);
```

inside `main ()` function

```
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;

    //code
    init_LCD ();

    show_Char('F',1);
    show_Char('O',2);
    show_Char('R',3);
    show_Char('A',4);
    show_Char('T',5);

    TURN_ON_LCD;

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Inside the `init_LCD ()`

```
void init_LCD (void)
{
     //code

    //configuring: COM0 COM1 COM2 COM3
    //R23 R13/LCDREF R03
    P6SEL1 |= (BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT3 | BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6);
    P6SEL0 |= (BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2 | BIT3 | BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6);

    LCDCCTL0 = (LCDPRE__16 | LCDDIV_3 | LCD4MUX | LCDLP);

    LCDCVCTL = 0x1E68;//external biasing
    //VLCD = 1111, LCDCPEN = 1, VLCDREF = 00, VLCD = 3.44V
    //R03EXT = 1, V5 sourced from R03 pin
    //LCDEXTBIAS = 1, V2 - V4 sourced externally, and internal bias generator is switched off
    //VLCDEXT = 0, VLCD (V1) is sourced internally from the Charge Pump
    //LCDPEN = 1, Charge Pump is enabled
    //LCD2B = 0, 1/3 Bias



    //LCDCVCTL = 0x1E08; //V2 - V4 generated internally

    LCDCCPCTL = LCDCPCLKSYNC;//TI

    CLEAR_LCD_MEM;

}
```

---

However, when I build and download the code into the development board, I don't see any segments being turned ON.

I changed the code to configure the LCD's bias to be sourced internally `LCDCVCTL = 0x1E08` which is `0001 1110 0000 1000`, and the LCD segments got turned ON.

```
LCDCVCTL = 0x1E08;
//VLCD = 3.44V
//Charge Pump enabled
//V1 generated internally
//V2 - V4
```

---

Kindly help me with this issue

Documents I used for reference:

- [Designing with MSP430 MCUs and Segment LCD Application Note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa654a/slaa654a.pdf?ts=1597120160798&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)
- [MSP-EXP430FR6989 User Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau627a/slau627a.pdf?ts=1597115662607&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FMSP-EXP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP-EXP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)
- [MSP430FR6989 User Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=159702537377%206&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)
- [MSP430FR6989 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6989.pdf?ts=1597025373666&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR6989%253FkeyMatch%253DMSP430FR6989%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)

Comment: If this is a naked LCD (no controller chip) you do know you need to drive it with an AC square wave, right? Does the MSP LCD controller need something enabled to do that for you? Can you see that square wave being generated in both working and non configurations?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes the MSP430 have an LCD driver (LCD_B and LCD_C modules), that takes care of that, we just need to set the correct segment and COM lines